# What types don't consume memory until assigned a non-default value?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management, types

VS memory profiler tells me that when I add a `byte` field to my class, it does not take any additional memory right at the start of application, but if it's an `int` or `object`, it takes additional 4 bytes per instance.

Are there any other types, or can I create my own that don't take up memory before assigned a value?
Also will the memory free up when the value becomes null (zero) again?

Comment: I don't believe there is such a type. At a minimum a reference type will occupy a 32 bits of memory, whether it was initialized or not.

Comment: @Oded A reference will be 32 bits on a 32 bit system, not just one byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory on a 32-bit platform is typically allocated in allocation units of 4 bytes.  I assume the .NET Runtime is doing just that.

The C# compiler uses a layout that results in the smallest allocation size for a class/struct (unless you use annotations to indicate otherwise, which one would do e.g. when using interop to communicate with unmanaged code that lays out memory differently).  That means that

- 4 *byte* variables need only take one allocation unit
- 2 *short* or *ushort* only take one allocation unit
- If you have an *int* and then a *byte*, that *byte* will still trigger use of another allocation unit.  You could then add up to 3 more *byte* variables without requiring another allocation unit.

Comment: So I can add more bytes without spending more memory. Neat.

Comment: @user1306322: Yes, as long as you stay within the memory allocation alignment of your .NET Runtime.  Different runtimes may follow different allocation strategies (I suspect for example that 64-bit Runtimes will allocate 8-byte units.  Runtimes for devices with less memory, e.g. phones or tablets, may well allocate in smaller allocation units).

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any. There's probably some minimum size the object has to be and byte is small enough to fit in the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Every declared variable occupies some memory, either on the stack or on the heap.

The one possible exception would local variables that could fit in a suitable register on the hardware in use. In that case, in certain contexts, the optimizer and the JIT compiler *might* (emphasis on "might") elect to allocate it to a register rather than allocate space on the stack frame for it.